# How to add icon when make installer with Visual Studio Installer?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I´m learning how to make installers with Visual Studio Installer (2015) but I can´t find much information and I don´t know how to include an icon that shows in in desktop and taskbar, right now I have it like this:

[image]

I know I can change it manually but that is not pro.

Thanks.

Ps: my project´s forms have an icon.